# 3D Positional Audio and Scenekit

Tags: audio, scenekit

I am having trouble with the NSViewcontroller.  Error says is of undeclared type 'NSViewController'.  I did import scenekit and avfoundation.  Seems as if NSViewController is unsupported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only code for Scenekit so don't know the entire apple foundation, but I use UIViewController for all of my scenekit games.